# Is my SQL Server mining bitcoins or just doing its job?

Tags: sql-server

Is there any method to check what SQL Server is doing now, when Activity Monitor is not very usefull:
[image]

I have got local instance which sometimes hits some 30% CPU and is not stopping. There is no running job/query and I cant see obvious reasons of such behavior...

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the CPU is due to other processes running on the machine. Check Performance Monitor or Task Manager.

Comment: `exec sp_who2` can give you info

Comment: Cant you see screenshots? There is one from AM and one from PM not helping much. sp_who2 not helping too...